# How to accept server connection or break out of accept() loop in Golang

Tags: go

I need to implement a server in Golang. I'm using the `net` package for this purpose but I do not understand how to break out from the `accept` loop gracefully.

So looking at the example from the `net` package:

```
ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8080")
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
for {
    conn, err := ln.Accept()
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
    }
    go handleConnection(conn)
}
```

I want to do something more along the lines of:

```
for {
    select {
    case <-done:
        break
    case conn, err := <-ln.Accept():
    if err != nil {
        break
    }
    ...
}
```

I other words, I want to be able to terminate the program gracefully somehow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best practice, with any service, to ensure a clean shutdown is to ensure each part of the service supports cancelation. Adding [context.Context](https://golang.org/pkg/context/) support is the recommended way to achieve this.

So first, ensure your `net.Listener` does not hang on rogue client connection. So to add `context.Context` support:

```
var lc net.ListenConfig

ln, err := lc.Listen(ctx, "tcp", ":8080")
```

Canceling `ctx` will break any rogue client connection here that may be blocking during handshake.

---

**EDIT:**
To ensure we can break out of the `Listen()` call while it is blocked waiting, one can leverage the same `ctx` state and (as noted in a previous, now deleted, answer) close the connection when a cancelation event is detected:

```
go func() {
    <-ctx.Done()
    log.Println("shutting service down...")
    ln.Close()
}()
```

Working example: https://play.golang.org/p/LO1XS4jBQ02